# Stored Procedure T-SQL If boolean check

Tags: t-sql, if-statement

An easy one for anyone who knows.  In TSQL Stored Procedures how do you write an if statement comparing the value of a bool.  Being accustomed to C# too long I'm putting in curly braces, round braces and all sorts and I think I'm getting it wrong.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
DECLARE @bool BIT = 1

IF @bool = 1
BEGIN
    -- do stuff here
    PRINT 'it was true';
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- do other stuff here
    PRINT 'it was not true';
END
```

If you've only got a single line inside the if then you don't need the `BEGIN` and `END`, but it's probably good practice to use them anyway.

Comment: where does an else go?  AFter or before the END?

Comment: I've added an ELSE clause to the answer - it goes after the END.

Answer (score 3):

The corresponding sql data type to boolean is bit, meaning 1 for true and 0 for false, so:

```
IF( @Statement=1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT MIN(ID) FROM Table
    END
END
```

Comment: Got an Extra `END` there.  `IF...ELSE...` doesn't terminate with an `END` keyword.  You only need them for each `BEGIN...END` block

Answer (score 3):

Starting with SQL Server 2012 IIF is shorthand way of writing IF THEN ELSE for assignment:

```
    DECLARE @str VARCHAR(10);
    SET @str = IIF(1=1, 'Yes', 'No');
```

Comment: Do note that IIF is only available starting with SQL Server 2012.